# Call httpBackend with same arguments but return different values

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a unit test where I am checking that a service polls a URL using $http. The first time round I want to return a value that will cause the service wait 10 seconds (using $timeout) and then to poll again. The second time round I want to return a value that will stop the service from polling.

When I do this

```
httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, { status: 'busy'});
httpBackend.expectGET(ulr).respond(200, { status: 'complete}');
service.poll();
httpBackend.flush();
timeout.flush();

httpBackend.verifyNoAllRequests();
```

However it never gets to the verification part. As soon as I do the timeout.flush() I get

```
Unsatisfied requests: GET /url/status/check
```

Comment: Perhaps your `service.poll()` is doing an extra URL request that isn't being mocked?

Comment: Nope, only the two. I stepped through it with Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, { status: 'busy'});
service.poll();
httpBackend.flush();
timeout.flush();
httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(200, { status: 'complete}');
httpBackend.flush();
```